# How to turn off / disable "CTRL LOCK"?

Tags: linux, lenovo-laptop, thinkpad, xmonad, nixos

I have a ThinkPad T520 with NixOS 21.09 installed with Xmonad. Locked the screen with `slock`, went to have lunch, and when I got back the cat was peacefully asleep on the keyboard. When unlocked, almost nothing seemed to be working: <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>..<kbd>9</kbd> (to switch workspaces in Xmonad), etc.

I figured out typing in the address bar in Chrome (the window that was active at the time of locking the screen) that the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key is permanently pressed, software-wise (removed both keys to see if they are stuck but they are fine).

I presume that this is some ThinkPad feature because it was activated while the `slock` was locking (and NUM LOCK was also on, which can only be activated via <kbd>FN</kbd>-<kbd>ScrLk</kbd>). Could be wrong though.

In the last half hour, the closest thing I could find is [this thread](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/80801/ctrl-key-locked-on/) but no joy. Any suggestions welcome and thanks in advance!

**Update**: Found the [T520 user manual](https://www.manualslib.com/products/Lenovo-Thinkpad-T520-1918029.html) but found no solution yet. A [thread](https://forums.lenovo.com/topic/view/1092/5077095) mentions <kbd>FN</kbd>-<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd> key combo but couldn't find it documented anywhere.

Also plugged in an external keyboard, same things happen.

**Update 2**: Disabled the "ctrl lock" but not sure how. Did random combos of keys <kbd>Fn</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>, and <kbd>Windows</kbd>, and sometimes held them for 5, 10, 15 seconds. Kind of  sure of the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key playing a significant role as it was part of all tries before giving way.

Would still be interested though...

Comment: start > run > osk | to make visible which keyboard button that is pressed or not pressed but active.

Answer (score 0):

This combo should work:
<kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this may answer the question, few more sentences explaining the answer would make this a better answer, more helpful both to OP and to others who may have the same problem.